# Is one Shinkansen better than two locomotives?

Tags: mini-metro

[image]

I find it hard to believe that one shinkansen is going to provide more capacity than two locomotives!

Comment: The answer from chicks is short, but does answer the question -- even if one shinkansen isn't as good as 2 locomatives, one shinkansen with a carriage is probably better than 2 locomatives and one carriage.

Comment: I can see now that I didn't directly answer the question before.  But I've updated it to connect the dots more clearly.  I hope that helps.

Answer (score 11):

The Shinkansen carries the same number of passengers as a normal locomotive, but it moves faster.  You can also add carriages to Shinkansen which also move fast to increase capacity.

Which is better depends on the circumstances.  If you have a line with lots of long stretches then the Shinkansen could definitely be helpful.  If you take any existing spare carriages and locomotives out, the question boils down to: **do you want half of the seat capacity for a single faster train**?  As 6005 commented the additional carriages makes a huge difference to this decision.  If you can't add any carriages to the Shinkansen the lower capacity will be a bigger detriment and I'd say the two locomotives will be easier to get further with.

Comment: (+1) the note about carriages is key.